# Bootstrap Collapse has snap\jitter

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap (3.3.6) collapse, with the collapsible DIVs located between form inputs\labels.  When the DIVs expand\hide, there's a sort of snap\jitter.

The code for the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/ybto1zvk/

I've seen similar post talk about jitter when one of the DIVs has padding, but as you can see, there's no styling except what bootstrap is applying...

Have tried with Chrome and Firefox, no difference.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name='radioinput' id="radio1"> One (click me)
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1">
    <div class="well">
      Sub 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name='radioinput' id="radio2"> Two
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-2">
    <div class="well">
      Sub 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name='radioinput' id="radio3"> Three
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-3">
    <div class="well">
      Sub 3
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#radio1').click(function() {
  $('#collapse-1').collapse('toggle');
  $('#collapse-2').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapse-3').collapse('hide');

});

$('#radio2').click(function() {
  $('#collapse-2').collapse('toggle');
  $('#collapse-1').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapse-3').collapse('hide');
});

$('#radio3').click(function() {
  $('#collapse-3').collapse('toggle');
  $('#collapse-1').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapse-2').collapse('hide');

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is being caused by the bottom margin property (set by bootstrap) on the well. Try adding:

```
    .well{margin:0}
```

To your css, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of collapsing margin. As per [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) Documentation:

> **Parent and first/last child:** If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

In your case `margin-bottom` of `.well` inside `.collapse` is creating this issue. You can solve this issue by many ways. But two ways are

1. Add `overflow: hidden` on parent
2. Remove `margin-bottom` from `.well`

Here is Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybto1zvk/3/)